# If the page is a script, add a handler. If the file should be downloaded, add a MIME map

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

iam getting this error from Local Hosting in Windoiws 7 (IIS).when im running my web application.can anyone know let me know.
HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension configuration. If the page is a script, add a handler. If the file should be downloaded, add a MIME map.thank in advance

Comment: Exactly what type of file were you trying to run?  What was the extension?

Comment: @Jane S-web application only-thank in advance

Comment: HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension configuration. If the page is a script, add a handler. If the file should be downloaded, add a MIME map

Comment: So...aspx? Html? cshtml? There are a _lot of web applications thT run on IIS ;)

Comment: @Jane S-aspx page sir

Comment: I'm actually a ma'am not a sir :)  Have you installed .NET on to the machine?